# OpenGL/C++ and Maya integration

Tags: c++, opengl, unity-game-engine, maya

I am wondering if it's possible to import the models that you made in softwares like Maya into your C++/OpenGL code so that you can use these models as your game characters?

If it is possible how am I supposed to do that?

If it's not possible or it's not the way people usually create 3d game characters what are the standard or preferable ways to create 3d characters and then use them in a c++ game program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite possible and commonly used. You can parse one of the many formats that Maya can export. For example, [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Load_OBJ) you can see a tutorial for the `obj` format.

Comment: obj is on its way out though.  Better to use fbx.

Comment: Collada is also quite common or you can read the data form Maya directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, and it is how I create all the game models for my own games made in C++/OpenGL.  You could use external resources like Collada, but I just wrote my own exporter using the Maya C++ API and my own importer for the game application.  It's quite easy to do.  For more information about how to write your own exporter, you can find Maya's API  manual [here](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/mayasdk2012/en_us/index.html).